# C++ using if-else statements to calculate sin and cos

Tags: c++, if-statement, trigonometry

Okay so I have to create a program in C++ using if-else statements to calculate the sin of a number entered if it is an odd number, or calculate the cos of a number if it is an even number. My program keeps failing, and i am not sure why. Could somebody give me a tip please on what I have done wrong?

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE SO FAR (My program keeps failing, so I don't know what to do next until i fix this problem)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    const double pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
    int a;

    cout << "Please type in a 2 digit number : " << endl;
    cin >> a;

    if(a % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << "The input is" << a << "It is an even number." << endl;
        cout << cos(a) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The input is" << a << "It is an odd number." << endl;
        cout << sin(a) << endl;
    }
} // main
```

Comment: 'My program keeps failing', in what **way** does it fail? I see no obvious errors. Why we have to keep asking for this I don't know.

Comment: @john how do I figure out the way it is failing?

Comment: Perhaps you are entering degrees? The c++ sin/cos expect radians

Comment: Sorry for the rant but you must be the tenth person recently who's just said 'my program doesn't work, please fix it'. We have to know what you expect the program to do and what it actually does.

Comment: @JamesSimon What he's asking is: What makes you say "it fails"? What happens and how is it different from what you want to happen? Compiler error, incorrect output, the program crashing, humanoid aliens appearing in your closet, that sort of thing.

Comment: You should describe what it does, you should describe what you expect it to do.

Comment: I think I have to convert something to radians as well?

Comment: Right, so your program input is in degrees, but sin and cos use radians. You see from what you described there was no way we could have known that the input was supposed to be degrees.

Comment: @john okay Im sorry. umm whenever i go to build a solution it tells me program failed. I have no idea why. I was expecting it to have an output that when I enter a number (61) it would calculate the sin of it and display that answer.

Comment: @john: I think it was rather obvious what he wanted...

Comment: @john alright so this is probably a stupid question, but in order to convert to radians would I have to use degree = radian * (180/pi)

Comment: @JamesSimon No the other way around `radians = degree/(180.0/pi);`. See my answer below.

Comment: @john I got ya man! Thanks for the help! and sorry for not being specific

Comment: @JamesSimon Any other error message when it says 'program failed.'?

Comment: @john nope it worked perfectly after that

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, sin and cos functions take a float or a double as input parameter. So you try something like this :

```
cout << cos(static_cast<double>(a)) << endl;
```

[How the cos function is working](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/cos)

Comment: That conversion happens automatically.

Comment: That should either only improve accuracy of the result slightly (if there's a `double` overload) or change nothing (because there's only a `double` definition and this change only makes an implicit promotion explicit). I'd need to know the standard library better than I do to tell which one.

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't a `cos` overload for `int`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want your program input to be in degrees, but this is a problem because `sin` and `cos` use radians. So you have to convert, like this

```
    cout << "The input is" << a << "It is an even number." << endl;
    double radians = (a/180.0)*pi;
    cout << cos(radians) << endl;
```

Same for odd numbers too.